# NPOI number wrong format read

Tags: number-formatting, xlsx, npoi

I have an xlsx file and try to read numbers from it and put them in another file. Problem is, that some numbers are read incorrectly and i have no idea why. For example:

```
Number in excel | Number read
-----------------------------
139,8           | 1,398E+16
2,2             | 2,2E+16
```

Interesting thing is, that this problem happens only with some numbers. Formatting for all numbers is the same. NPOI reads the exact number from excel, not the formatted, so i checked values, but hey all are the same as formatted ones.

Ok, i guess i found a problem. Now i just need to find solution. I Extracted xlsx file and checked the real values stored in cells. Problem is that when i have value `139.80000000000001` it is read as `1,398E+16`, so i guess NPOI interpretes the formatting wrong. It thinks that . (dot) separates thousands, while it doesn't.

Comment: Now i set cell type as `STRING` before i read the value. Then i replace `'.'` with `','` and convert it to `double`. It works for me, but maybe there is a better way to achieve that?

Comment: I unfortunately experienced the same issue with NPOI from nuget, version 2.4.1. I am wondering that the issue came back again?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I just updated from Alpha to Beta, and it worked. Now I get the exact value that is on the cell.

The beta can be found [here](http://npoi.codeplex.com/releases/view/97124).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known issue, and there's a planned fix in an upcoming [NPOI 2.0 beta 1 release](http://npoi.codeplex.com/releases/view/97124):

> RELEASE NOTES
>
> - ...
> - fix decimal seperated by comma instead of dot

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a bug in NPOI 2.0 alpha. Please try NPOI 2.0 beta 1 if it still exists, we will plan to fix it in 2.0 final release